# how can I fade in and out different texts on the same UILabel in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, swift3, animatewithduration

Currently I have an array of strings in my `swift` and I'm displaying them in a loop on the `UILabel`:

```
let greetings = ["Test1", "Test2", "Test3", "Test4"]

override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()
    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2.0, target: self, selector: #selector(TutorialEntryPoint.update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

var i = 0
func update() {
    if(i==4){
        i=0
    }
    myLabel.text = greetings[i]
    i += 1 
}
```

That works, but each text disappears and shows suddenly - is there a way of modifying it so that each text disappears/shows smoothly? I thought about using `animateWithDuration` and modifying `alpha`, but I'm not sure how to do it properly.

Comment: Instead of checking `i`, you can also use `greetings[i % greetings.count]`.

Comment: @HennyLee hmm what exactly do you mean? Sorry, I'm just learning swift :)

Comment: By using `greetings[i % greetings.count]` you can increase `i` without having to worry to be out of bounds. `100 % greetings.count` is the same as `0` in your case. That's because `%` is a modulo. The result will be the remainder when dividing. For example, “5 % 3 = 2” which means 2 is the remainder when you divide 5 by 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can animate setting text on label like this

```
UIView.transition(with: label,
                      duration: 0.25,
                      options: [.transitionCrossDissolve],
                      animations: {
                      label.text = "Your Text"
}, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

Could try something like this

```
    //inside viewDidLoad
    let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation()
    animation.keyPath = "opacity"
    animation.values = [0, 1, 1, 0]
    animation.keyTimes = [0, 0.1, 0.9, 1]
    animation.duration = 2.0 //same as your timer
    animation.repeatCount = Float.infinity

    myLabel.layer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "fade")
```

haven't tested it, so may need some tweaking, but ive used something like this to fade something in and out before

Answer (score 0):

I tried several variations of this over the course of a few days, and the best solution I found was here: https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/swift-3-so-i-wanted-to-animate-a-label-14dd2b332ef9

The variables & functions have to be changed to account for `String` types rather than `Int`s. I was using an array of strings (as in the question here), so I incremented an index after `setTextValue` on line 131.